# Is using the address of an uninitialized variable UB?

Tags: c, printf, undefined-behavior, variadic-functions

Is this small code UB?

```
void Test()
{
  int bar;
  printf("%p", &bar);  
}
```

IMO it's not UB, but I'd like some other opinions.

It simply prints the address of `bar`, even if `bar` has never been initialized.

Comment: What about `printf("%d", bar);`? I remember some discussion differentiating between undefined and indeterminate...

Comment: `printf("%p", &bar);` ->  `printf("%p", (void*)&bar); `. This is probably not central to your question but C standard requires it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `printf("%d", bar);` is definitly UB, it will print whatever is in memory at the address of `bar`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz But what you are saying is not UB, but just printing indeterminate value. UB is technically something allowed to summon nasal demons.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I understand your point of view, but UB is a very large concept, anyway for me printing a non predictable value is also "undefined behaviour".

Comment: @MichaelWalz: It is not unpredictable, but indeterminate. Unless it is a trap representation, it is not UB. And trap representations on integers are pretty rare nowadays.

Comment: @Olaf, Annex J.2 cites "The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate" as one of the sources of undefined behavior.  On the other hand, that annex is not normative, and I'm having trouble finding normative provisions supporting it in this regard.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Hmm, I had something in mind about only trap representations invoke UB. But then, I never use such nonsense, so I'm not 100% sure. After all: who cares? It is just useless.

Comment: @Olaf `{ int bar; printf("%d", bar); }` is be UB. From 6.3.2.1: If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the register storage class (never had its address taken), and that object is **uninitialized** ... the **behavior is undefined**.

Comment: @Riley even if `bar` was declared with the (now obsolete) `register` storage class, the compiler should be smart enough not to put the variable into a register if it's address is used somewhere in the program.

Comment: @Riley: 6.3.2.1 is about conversion. Not sure how that is relevant here. AFAIS, the cited text is not from that section. Also an actual function parameter is not required to be an lvalue. And it is certainly not necessary to initialise an automatic object, but to have it determinate (resp. not indeterminate). Anyway, I don't care enough to continue; as I wrote above, be it UB or not, it is useless and wrong code anyway.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: `register` is not obsolete, it just has typically not the same intention when used it had decades ago. (as long the user is aware of the changed relevance).

Comment: @MichaelWalz Even if the compiler is smart enough to do something useful, UB is still UB.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Unfortunately, unless something has  changed, the Standard mandate that taking the address of a `register` variable is a constraint violation (thus requiring that even compilers where it would serve no useful purpose must record the qualifier's existence).  Were that not the case, the Standard could attach useful meaning to the qualifier by saying that a compiler may assume a register variable will not be accessed via pointer anywhere that is sequenced before or after evaluation of a complete expression taking its address, and will be accessed *only* via pointer...

Comment: ...during the evaluation of such an expression.  This, given `int register r;`, something like `get_int(&r)` would be equivalent to `int temp123 = r; get_int(&temp123); r=temp123;`, but far less verbose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL:DR** No, your code does not invoke UB by using anything *uninitialized*, as you might have thought.

---

The address of a(ny) variable (automatic, in this case) has a *defined* value, so irrespective of whether the variable itself is initialized or not, the address of the variable is a *defined value*. You can make use of that value. ( *if you're not dealing with pointers and doing double-dereference. :)* )

That said, strictly speaking, you should write

```
 printf("%p", (void *)&bar);
```

as `%p` expects an argument of type pointer to `void` and `printf()` being a variadic function, no promotion (*conversion*) is performed. Otherwise, this is a well-defined behavior.

`C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1

> `p` The argument shall be a pointer to `void`. [.....]

Comment: But isn't `void*` compatible with any pointer type ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz how?

Comment: @MichaelWalz, any pointer can be *converted* to type `void *`, but no such conversion happens with variadic arguments, such as the second and subsequent arguments to `printf()`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: It **can be converted to**. But how should a variadic parameter be known which actual type it has, or the caller know what the callee expects?

Comment: ... so, in other words, it *does* invoke UB.

Answer (score 4):

> Is this small code UB?

Yes, it's UB because the conversion specifier `p` *requires* a `void`-pointer.

On the other hand the code below does not invoke UB

```
void Test(void)
{
  int bar;
  printf("%p", (void*) &bar);  
}
```

as the address of `bar` is well defined independently whether `bar` itself got initialised.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is well defined.

The address of the variable is known.  The fact that it hasn't been explicitly initialized doesn't matter.